# Make following div expand to bottom and then scroll

Tags: html, css

I have the following design

[image]

*How can I make the orange div expand from head to bottom, and then scroll if the content is bigger, but at the same time keep the footer at the bottom of the page?*

I tried postioning the div as `position:absolute` with a `bottom:footers's height` and `overflow-y:scroll`, but if I do that it overlaps with the head.

Comment: The functionality you re looking for is "fixed head and fixed footer, scrollable div" , right ?

Comment: @FurkanOrhan exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `header` and `footer` elements to be `position: fixed` to the top and bottom respectively. From there you just need to add `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to the central content div so that the content within it won't overlap. Try this:

```
<header></header>
<div id="content"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

```css
header {
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    padding: 150px 0 100px;
}

footer {
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/56fLda6w/)

Answer (score 1):

I understand, that the header is supposed to scroll with the page unlike the footer, so the easiest solution is this: give the fotter `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0` and to the div apply `margin-bottom: X` where X is the height of the footer.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this?

```css
body {text-align:center}
.header {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; height:50px; background:orange; color:white;}
.content {box-sizing:border-box; min-height:200vh; padding-top:50px; padding:bottom:50px;}
.footer {position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; height:50px; background:red; color:white;}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

By setting `box-sizing:border-box;` and `min-height:100vh;`, you are setting the min-height to the window height regardless of padding or borders.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you need.

```css
#H,#B,#F{
  widht: 100%;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

#H{
  background: Orange;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#B{
  background: White;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#F{
  background: gray;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="H">Header</div>
<div id="B">Body<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
<div id="F">Footer</div>
```